# numpy.savez and npy-matlab together

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy, save

I have used the [npy-matlab](https://github.com/kwikteam/npy-matlab) package to load numpy arrays (saved using numpy.save) into matlab. However, I would like to save multiple numpy arrays in a single file by using numpy.savez. I think the package does not support this option, because I am receiving the following error:

> Error: This file does not appear to be NUMPY format based on the header.

Is there a simple work around to this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: `savez` saves each array into a separate `.npy` file, and collects them into one `zip` archive.  If `npy-matlab` can read `npy` files, then you probably have to extract them from the archive first.

Comment: You are right, I did not notice that the file extension was .npz, instead of .npy. Thanks.